# VBA - Find all same values in a column with a condition

Tags: excel, vba

this is my table:

```
      A          B
1    YES        APPLE 
2    NO         APPLE
3    YES        PEAR
4    YES        PEAR
5    YES        ORANGE
6    NO         BANANA
7    YES        APPLE
```

(1) Find all match values in row B, input 'APPLE' (Results: `B1` / `B2` / `B7`)

(2a) If `B1` AND `B2` AND `B3` = YES then return "MATCH"

other input:

(2b) If only one result found (`B5`) = YES then return "MATCH"

(2c) If only one result found (`B6`) = NO then return "NO MATCH"

How can I do it by VBA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C1 put

```
=CONCATENATE(A1;B1)
```

In D1 put

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("NO"&B1;C$1:C$7;1;FALSE));"MATCH";"NO MATCH")
```

Just change the 7 number in the formula to whatever the last row of your range is. Then copy both formulas down to the last row of your range.